# Composer - Prevent from installing ZF2 files

Tags: php, zend-framework2, composer-php

I started working on my new ZF2 webapp and during the Composer configuration (installation of Doctrine, ZDT, ZFTool, etc.), I noticed that Composer always install ZF2 files or components during downloading, even if it is included in `php.ini` in `zf2_path`.

Is there a way to prevent Composer from always installation ZF2 in the `./vendor` directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Composer knows nothing about your `include_path` and installs everything locally. And this is a good thing, because you get the version, which your projects needs and it doesn't clash with other projects.

If you want to use shared dependencies, then composer is, probably, not for you.

Comment: I only use a shared version of ZF2, which is in my `/usr/share/php` directory. Everything else is under `./vendor`.

Comment: well… composer can't handle that. sorry

Comment: Well, hope they will do something for that someday!